# Email service not receiving emails due to dns issue

Tags: dns, email, mx

I have a domain (let's say **ga...ot.ch**) bought from a domain registrar. The registrar has offered me a free email which I am using. However, the email can only send but not receive.
This is my configuration and I don't know which one to fix:

[image]

This image is from Infomaniak (the domain registrar)

As you can see in the picture the **NS Record** is pointing to my web server hosted in digital ocean because that is where the website is. So these two records are correct as far as I can tell.

But the email is provided by infomaniak.ch, for which I changed the MX but I am still unable to receive email, I can only send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your NS records are pointing at digitalocean.com, none of the other record types (A, CNAME, MX, TXT) that you have set at Infomaniak have any effect.  You'll need to log into digitalocean and set your MX record there (along with any of the other records that are important.)

NS records are always set at the domain registrar and specify your DNS host.  Since you changed your DNS host by setting the NS records, you need to make all your DNS settings at your new DNS host (digitalocean).

You say that the "NS Record is pointing to my web server" but that isn't technically correct.  The NS records are pointing to the DNS servers at digitalocean.  Dititalocean's DNS servers will have the A and CNAME records that point to your web server.

Here is a diagram to help you think of it conceptually which is from my blog post about this subject [Myth: You need to change your DNS NS records to point to your web host](https://blog.ostermiller.org/webhosting-dns-ns/).

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this was very helpful